# PrimeFaces file upload stopped working

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a problem with file upload using PrimeFaces. I went through old post here on StackOverflow a didn't find anything useful. Strange thing is that I made it work yesterday but I started my server now and it's working anymore. It's giving me NPE when I try to access the uploaded file.

So I downloaded commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar and commons-io-1.4, put them in my classpath, configured my `web.xml` like this

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

My form in xhtml page contains one field with description, one combo box and field upload element

```
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:panel header="#{submitProjectPage['header']}">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    #{submitProjectPage['chooseProject']}
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{submitProjectBean.project}" converter="projectConverter">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{submitProjectBean.studentsProjects}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

And finally my bean is `RequestScoped` and has this method

```
private UploadedFile projectFile;

public void submitProject(ActionEvent event) {//also tried without parameter
    project.setFile(projectFile.getContents());
    project.setStatus(StatusEnum.DELIVERED);
    daoBean.update(project);
}
                    #{submitProjectPage['submitInformation']}
                    <p:inputTextarea rows="10" value="#{submitProjectBean.s}"/>
                    #{submitProjectPage['file']}
                    <p:fileUpload value="#{submitProjectBean.projectFile}" mode="simple" />

                    <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="#{submitProjectPage['submit']}" 
                                    actionListener="#{submitProjectBean.submitProject}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
```

I am sure I have my imports right, there is also a setter for projectFile field so I really don't know where could be the problem. I am using PrimeFaces v 3.01

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the thing was that Glassfish for some reason didn't deploy the apache libraries, so I removed them from classpath, added them again and it magically works:-)

So maybe it will help somebody:)